# Jenkins BlueOcean unable to connecto to GIT repo URL

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-blueocean

I have implemented a sample CI/CD pipeline using Jenkins for an application.
The GIT URL for the private repository specified in code checkout job works fine.

But when I use the same GIT Repo url to create a pipeline using "Blue Ocean" plugin it is throwing the following error:

`Repository URL - Please enter a valid URL.`

Can anyone please help what can be the possible error as I am unable to figure out as the normal job in the pipeline is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using http or https use ssh while providing the url, please see below or follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47356307/jenkins-blue-ocean-with-tfs-2013-git-saving-pipelines-is-unsupported-using-h):-

```
ssh://user@server:/GitRepo/project.git
```

Comment: Should I register the SSH public key first and try using the url? I am facing the same issue again even though I am using SSH.

Comment: yes you have to register first, please follow the steps from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47356307/jenkins-blue-ocean-with-tfs-2013-git-saving-pipelines-is-unsupported-using-h

Comment: Actually I am using scm-manager instead of Github for managing the repositories,it that causing an issue over here.

Comment: By default scm-manager supports only http, so for supporting ssh you will need SSH Plugin for SCM Manager as it enables SSH access to Git repositories.